# How to query module (Potentials) on modified time using Vtiger API

Tags: api, crm, vtiger

Currently I'm using Vtiger API **sync operation** to fetch last modified **Potentials**. But the issue with sync is that it fetch only those records that are assigned to the user who is performing the operation. Actually I want all the Potentials added/modified by all the users.

Now I'm trying same using Query operation. My params looks like this:

```
var hourAgo = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() -  60 * 60 * 1000) / 1000);
var params = "operation=query&sessionName=" + SESSION_ID + "&query=Select * from Potentials where modifiedtime > hourAgo;"
```

Seems like query is returning all the records instead of last modified records.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

P.s. I'm using Apps script to do this one.

Comment: the format of variable hourago and timezone difference between vtiger server and your app can also effect. Are you getting records modified days before ?

Comment: Thanks @lajeeshk for comment. I already got the answer. It was issue with timezone. Once I change my timezone to  "UTC" which Vtiger use, I got correct records.